# The state variable doesn't store JSON response before it's displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**Context**: I am retrieving a JSON response from a GET request with Axios that uses Async/Await. It is stored in a state variable called `tutorDetails` within the `useMemo` hook. I am accessing the stored state variable in React JSX within the `return` code block, but it's not populated with the intended JSON response prior to displaying the content.

**Question**: Is there a way I can ensure the return JSX code block is only processed after the state variable has been populated? If not, please suggest any other workarounds.

```js
import React, {useState, useMemo} from "react";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';
import axios from 'axios';

 function TutorCard({tutor_id, first_name, last_name, grade, subject}) {
    return (
        <div className="md:flex bg-white shadow text-gray-800 my-4 py-4 px-10 rounded-md items-center justify-between hover:bg-gray-300"  >
            {/* <img
                style={{ maxWidth: "60px"}}
                className="rounded-full shadow-md border border-gray-300"
                src={image}
                alt="employee"
            /> */}
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center"}}>{tutor_id}</p>
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center"}}>{first_name}</p>
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{last_name}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{grade}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{subject}</p>
            <AlertDialogSlide tutorID = {tutor_id} firstName = {first_name} lastName = {last_name} grade = {grade} subject = {subject} />
        </div>
    )
}




const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

function AlertDialogSlide(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const [tutorDetails, setTutorDetails] = useState([ ])

components (componentDidMount, componentWillMount)
    useMemo( () => {
    const retrieveData = async () => {
        const resp = await axios.get('API call' + props.tutorID);
        console.log("Tutor Info Response: " + JSON.stringify(resp.data));
        console.log("AltSubjects: " + JSON.stringify(resp.data.subjects[0]));
        setTutorDetails(resp.data);

    }

    retrieveData();
}, []);

    

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        {'>'}
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        fullWidth = {true}
      >
        <DialogTitle>{props.firstName + " " + props.lastName}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText >
            <strong>Level: </strong> {props.grade} <br/>
            <strong>Subject: </strong> {props.subject} <br/>
            {/* <div> {(tutorDetails.subjects).map(sub => <div>  <strong>Alternative Subject: </strong> {JSON.stringify(sub)} <br/> </div>)} </div> */}
            <strong>Alternative Subject: </strong> {tutorDetails.subjects[0]} <br/>
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
export default TutorCard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) to fetch data across the network, not [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo). Also, depending on what you are doing with `tutorDetails` in your JSX, and because the callback of a `useEffect` runs after the JSX is rendered, a loader may make sense, to avoid errors:

```js
const [tutorDetails, setTutorDetails] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
  const retrieveData = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get("API_URL" + props.tutorID);
    setLoading(false);
    setTutorDetails(resp.data);
  };

  retrieveData();
}, [props.tutorID]);

if (loading) {
  return "Loading...";
}

return <div>Actual Content</div>
```